# Print all variables captured by closure

Tags: go, closures

How do I print out all variables that are captured by a closure? For example:

```
func myScope() {
  users := GetUsers("John")
  services := GetServices("Movies")
  allVariablesString := func() string {
    return PrintAllCapturesWithoutSpecified()
  }()
}
```

I plan to utilize this idea if possible to log any involved values within the scope of an error without manually specify each variable.

Comment: You can't at runtime. The compiler probably won't even include variables in the scope if there's no references to them.

Comment: @JimB That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible in Go. You can't ask for your surrounding environment in a closure. It's there to use, but you can't view/read it. You could do something weird like have them in a struct and view your struct, but depending on what you do, that could get very messy and non-idiomatic.